# Web application development using MS Access

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, ms-access

I have a problem with access database. I am developing a web application in visual studio 2010 using C#. I was using sql server 2005 as my database. Recently it is changed into Access. When I am trying to save some data to the Access database from my application it won't work. But when I am trying to do the same from Access itself it works correctly. What is the problem and what will I do for rectifying this problem.

Comment: The first thing you should do is post your connection/insertion code.

Comment: Access/Jet/ACE is really an inapropriate data store for a web-based application. You can get by with it for small apps with few users and few writes, but it's not designed for that purpose and comes with a number of serious problems.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton : I know that, but what can I do? Client decides such things and our duty is to develop applications which client asks.Actually I don't know access because I never used it before. I used only MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some difference with query in ms-access.Like if you have to query with date column then you have to use #+date+# instead of '+date+'